# how to find position of circles between lines in d3 polar scatter chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm drawing polar scatter chart in d3.

**How to calculate positions of circles between lines so they will not overlap the lines. ?**

Drawing lines:

This `d.angle` is position of line in radians on circle.  Every line has style `stroke-width: 3px`;

```
   svg
        .selectAll('Lines')
        .data(themeCoordinates)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .append('line')
        .attr('x1', 0)
        .attr('y1', 0)
        .attr('x2', (d) => {
          return linear(1) * Math.cos(d.angle);
        })
        .attr('y2', (d) => {
          return linear(1) * Math.sin(d.angle);
        });
```

2.
 The **calcTrendRadius** function calculates in which annulus should be draw circle (0-20km), (20-40km)

**calcTrendCoordinates** func give me an interval (angle) in which part should I draw circle f.e (North (Math.PI/2), North-East (2* Math.PI)) or (North-East,East).  The input param themeCoordinates give me interval according to second input param `trendObj.themeName`.

```
const linear = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([minDomain, maxDomain])
  .range([0, radius]);


  const calculateDataPosition = () => {
      const dataPosition = data.map((trendObj) => {
        const trendRadius = calcTrendRadius(trendObj.stage);
        const { x, y } = calcTrendCoordinates(
          themeCoordinates,
          trendObj.themeName
        );
        return {
          x: linear(trendRadius) * x, // position of circle on x axis
          y: linear(trendRadius) * y,  //position of circle on y axis
          ...trendObj
        };
      });
    };
```

and finally, here is how I'm drawing circle:

```
const wrapper = svg
        .selectAll('Points')
        .data(newData)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', (d, i) => {
          return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')';
        })
      wrapper
        .append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'point')
        .attr('r', circleRadius)
        .attr('fill', (d, i) => d.color);
```

These picture is just for illustration. I'm drawing only circles. In my case some circles are overlapping lines because their coordinates are calculated randomly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calculate intersection of circle and line recursively till circle is not intersected by line.  I used an existing solution here:  https://bl.ocks.org/milkbread/11000965.